# ShellExecuteA cannot find file

Tags: c++, windows, shellexecute

I'm trying to open a file with a c++ program using ShellExecuteA in Windows10. (I'm also using VisualStudio2019 in case that's relevant.) 
ShellExecute itself is working (I can use "explore" and "find" as it is intended), however it seems to be unable to find the file even though it exists in the directory. I have tried both an absolute as well as a relative path and neither work.
My code is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <string>
#include <limits.h>

using namespace std;

string getCurrentDir() {
    char buff[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, buff, MAX_PATH);
    string::size_type position = string(buff).find_last_of("\\/");
    return string(buff).substr(0, position);
}


int main()
{
    cout << "path: " << getCurrentDir() << endl;
    int ret1 = (int)ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", "C:\\Users\\Sasha\\source\\repos\\shellopen\\Debug\\MyTextFile.txt", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    cout << ret1 << endl;
    int ret2 = (int)ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", "MyTextFile.txt", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    cout << ret2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The result is

```
path: C:\Users\Sasha\source\repos\shellopen\Debug
2
2
```

"2" apparently means that the file couldn't be found, however "MyTextFile.txt" definitely exists in the directory and there is no spelling mistake. 
I've tried googling the problem but it seems to be uncommon enough that I haven't found anything that works for me. I'd be very grateful for any help.

Comment: You should display what `GetModuleFileName` originally gives you, instead of assuming what it is.

Comment: *"MyTextFile.txt" definitely exists in the directory and there is no spelling mistake* -- No one here knows this to be a fact.  Unless we have access to your machine, this cannot be verified.

Comment: Call [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) for extended error information.

Comment: GetModuleFileName does not tell you anything about current directory. Use GetCurrentDirectory.

Comment: The executable's install directory, and the process's current working directory, and two completely different things. You are looking in the former, but the latter is likely pointing somewhere else.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie was right - I actually had a spelling mistake caused by Windows hiding/adding the file extension when displaying it, making the filename "MyTextFile.txt.txt". Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turned out it was a spelling mistake, causing my file to be named "MyTextFile.txt.txt"
Thank you to everyone who tried to help me find the answer.

Comment: Put the OS into programmer mode: https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/10570-file-extensions-hide-show.html

Comment: You should update your original question!